# Updating master sheet from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from source sheet into a master sheet.

- If there is any existing record in the master sheet, update the record in the master sheet with the latest data from source sheet.
- Otherwise add the data from source sheet into the master sheet.

I pieced together code for one customer (single sheet).

How could I modify it to allow updating of multiple sheets?

I understand I need looping of worksheets but I am hitting errors.

````vb
Sub Update()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, srcLastRow As Long, destLastRow As Long, srcFndVal As String, destFndCell As Range, srcValRow As Long, destValRow As Long, destFndVal As String, srcFndCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Cust A")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Master")
    srcLastRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "BA").End(xlUp).Row
    destLastRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With wsDest
            For i = 4 To srcLastRow
            srcFndVal = wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA")
            Set destFndCell = .Range("A:A").Find(srcFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If destFndCell Is Nothing And wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA").Value <> "" Then
                    .Range("A" & j & ":F" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AA" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & j & ":K" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & i & ":AH" & i).Value
                    .Range("G" & j & ":H" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AE" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                    j = j + 1
                Else
            srcValRow = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsSrc.Range("AA4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            destValRow = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsDest.Range("A4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                    .Range("B" & destValRow & ":F" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AB" & srcValRow & ":AF" & srcValRow).Value
                    .Range("J" & destValRow & ":K" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & srcValRow & ":AH" & srcValRow).Value
                End If
            Next
            For k = 4 To destLastRow
            destFndVal = wsDest.Cells(k, "A")
            Set srcFndCell = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(destFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If srcFndCell Is Nothing And wsDest.Cells(k, "A").Value <> "" Then
                    .Range("B" & k & ":F" & k).Value = vbNullString
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I modified the code to loop through the worksheets in an array however there is an issue with getting the last row of the wsSrc.

>Run-time error 424 Object required.

Below line is highlighted

    srcLastRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

```vba
Sub Update()
    Dim wsSrc As Variant, srcList As Variant, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, srcLastRow As Long, destLastRow As Long, srcFndVal As String, destFndCell As Range, srcValRow As Long, destValRow As Long, destFndVal As String, srcFndCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    srcList = Array("Cust A", "Cust B", "Cust C", "Cust D", "Cust E", "Cust F", "Cust G")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Master")
    srcLastRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    destLastRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    For Each wsSrc In srcList
        With wsDest
            For i = 4 To srcLastRow
            srcFndVal = wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA")
            Set destFndCell = .Range("A:A").Find(srcFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If destFndCell Is Nothing And wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA").Value <> "" Then
                    .Range("A" & j & ":F" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AA" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & j & ":K" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & i & ":AH" & i).Value
                    .Range("G" & j & ":H" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AE" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                    j = j + 1
                Else
            srcValRow = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsSrc.Range("AA4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            destValRow = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsDest.Range("A4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                    .Range("B" & destValRow & ":F" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AB" & srcValRow & ":AF" & srcValRow).Value
                    .Range("J" & destValRow & ":K" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & srcValRow & ":AH" & srcValRow).Value
                End If
            Next
            For k = 4 To destLastRow
            destFndVal = wsDest.Cells(k, "A")
            Set srcFndCell = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(destFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If srcFndCell Is Nothing And wsDest.Cells(k, "A").Value <> "" Then
                    .Range("B" & k & ":F" & k).Value = vbNullString
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next wsSrc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
````

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Update()
    Dim wsSrc  As Worksheet
    For Each wsSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsSrc.Name <> "Master" Then
            'Do bla bla...
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fix your code. Try this.
Your matter is wsSrc is a WorkSheet Object, but srcList is an array of String. They are not match each other.
I use a condition that wsSrc name start with "Cust" instead. Tell me if this solved your problem

```
Sub Update()
    Dim wsSrc, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Dim srcLastRow, destLastRow, srcValRow, destValRow As Long
    Dim srcFndVal, destFndVal As String
    Dim destFndCell, srcFndCell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Master")
    For Each wsSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(wsSrc.Name, 4) = "Cust" Then
            srcLastRow = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "BA").End(xlUp).Row
            destLastRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            j = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            With wsDest
                For i = 4 To srcLastRow
                    srcFndVal = wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA")
                    Set destFndCell = .Range("A:A").Find(srcFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If destFndCell Is Nothing And wsSrc.Cells(i, "AA").Value <> "" Then
                        .Range("A" & j & ":F" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AA" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                        .Range("J" & j & ":K" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & i & ":AH" & i).Value
                        .Range("G" & j & ":H" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AE" & i & ":AF" & i).Value
                        j = j + 1
                    Else
                        srcValRow = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsSrc.Range("AA4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                        destValRow = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:=srcFndVal, after:=wsDest.Range("A4"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                        .Range("B" & destValRow & ":F" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AB" & srcValRow & ":AF" & srcValRow).Value
                        .Range("J" & destValRow & ":K" & destValRow).Value = wsSrc.Range("AG" & srcValRow & ":AH" & srcValRow).Value
                    End If
                Next
                For k = 4 To destLastRow
                    destFndVal = wsDest.Cells(k, "A")
                    Set srcFndCell = wsSrc.Range("AA:AA").Find(destFndVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If srcFndCell Is Nothing And wsDest.Cells(k, "A").Value <> "" Then .Range("B" & k & ":F" & k).Value = vbNullString
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```